# Can TeamCity 6.0.3 Be Set to Show Time in a 12-hour Format?

Tags: teamcity

In TeamCity 6.0.3, is there a way to set the time format to show 12-hour time format instead of 24-hour time format?  For example, I would like times to show 2:00 PM instead of 14:00.  I found the user-specific setting to show time in the user's timezone but this still displays time in 24-hour format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid, we don't provide such a possibility.